# Warning note when data has reached 14.5

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

this is my first question on stack overflow so i am not sure how to post in the right way, i hope i do well :).

I have a question regarding my prediction model in python.
I have made my first prediction model and now that i have made the prediction i would also like to have a note or message when the prediction has reached a value => 14,5. So just a small message with "Please check machine" when reached 14,5.

see prediction graph in figure and small portion of the code i have written.
[Prediction graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sVky.png)

[Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5Gz.png)

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_train_inv = cnt_transformer.inverse_transform(y_train.reshape(1, -1))
y_test_inv = cnt_transformer.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(1, -1))
y_pred_inv = cnt_transformer.inverse_transform(y_pred)

plt.plot(np.arange(0, len(y_train)), y_train_inv.flatten(), 'g', label="history")
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_train), len(y_train) + len(y_test)), y_test_inv.flatten(), marker='.', label="true")
plt.plot(np.arange(len(y_train), len(y_train) + len(y_test)), y_pred_inv.flatten(), 'r', label="prediction")
plt.ylabel('DP inlet')
plt.xlabel('Time Step')
plt.legend()
plt.show();

#Output see figure

plt.plot(y_test_inv.flatten(), marker='.', label="true")
plt.plot(y_pred_inv.flatten(), 'r', label="prediction")
plt.ylabel('DP inlet')
plt.xlabel('timestamp')
plt.legend()
plt.show();

#Output see figure
```

Comment: Please add the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Welcome on SO, then read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), your question currently fails on both criteria ;)